# Flutter debug Apk decompile to get the source code

Tags: flutter, decompiler

I have lost the source code of my flutter application due to drive corruption, but I have my `debug.apk` in my android phone.
How can I decompile the Flutter `apk` to get source code?
I have tried decompiling it using decompilers but it is not giving my source code
as the Flutter source code is in Dart language.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get the source code from an APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file)

Comment: flutter applications source code is in dart language , can java decompilers decompile other language code ?

Comment: try it and let us know

Comment: sure , btw I recovered my project using easeus and now its running fine. Thanks for your concern .

Comment: @F-1 I have tried decompiling the apk and I am not getting my dart code .

Comment: @estn I am new to this community sir , I haven't asked a duplicate question but it is showing this question may have an answer here . can you please tell me sir how to remove that . I already edit my question with more specific info but it is still showing the same.

Comment: @JagrajSingh have you find a solution?

Comment: @LuigiSaggese No , not yet . btw I had tried java decompilers but got nothing .

Comment: @JagrajSingh The same question as Luigi: do you have a solution now?

Comment: Well I tried @user3467955 's answer and I got small code snippets rather full code. You could try that .

Comment: Better use github/gitlab :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If your debug.apk is in debug mode then you can use `apktool` in order to extract the components of the `apk` (I'm using the word extracting since `apk` is a zip file).

Flutter, in debug mode, keeps the source code (with comments!) in the file kernel_blob.bin. Thus, using the following command should help you extract the code into a file:

```
strings /path/to/extracted/apk/assets/flutter_assets/kernel_blob.bin > extracted_code.dart
```

Please, **pay attention** - You'll need to clean 'extracted_code.dart', from irrelevant/garbage strings.

Try to search strings like "dart", "import", "void" and other keywords in 'extracted_code.dart', it will help you find the code itself.

Here's an example from my Ubuntu:

[image: Example]

If the `apk` is compiled in "release" mode, extracting the code will be much harder, since the code is compiled into isolate_snapshot_instr file, which is not a raw arm assembly, and is only deserialized using the Flutter engine in run-time. You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Flutter-engine-operation-in-AOT-Mode)

Comment: Better search for filename, your class names, or some regex like `runApp\(.*\(\)\);` in vscode or using `sed`. Because the file would be very big eg: 25MB and `470850` lines.

Comment: Please how do i perform this operation on windows. Windows can't seem to find command "strings". Thanks

Comment: Hey, you can [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/strings](download strings) for your Windows machine

Comment: https://medium.com/@rondalal54/reverse-engineering-flutter-apps-5d620bb105c0

Comment: REALLY THANKS!!! It works. Was writing a game with my son, and everything got lost during Git operations. And this helped! There was a lot of byte code, but search by file and variable names worked.