# Download flutter app and code back to laptoo

Tags: flutter, backup

I was almost finished building my first app with Flutter with VScode when my laptops hard drive crashed. All my code gone... I know I should have made a back up and really learnt my lesson now.. I have the app installed on my phone. Is there a way to get it back on my laptop with the full code?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the debug APK you might have a shot. Have a look at this: [Flutter debug Apk decompile to get source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53666487/flutter-debug-apk-decompile-to-get-source-code)

If you don't have the debug APK you are probably in trouble. The code on your phone is compiled and deliberately obfuscated, since usually you want to prevent someone with your app from getting the source code.

Really hope you can get it back. Good luck

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I bought my laptop 3 months ago so at least it is still in ganrantee. I will go tomorrow to the repair center and let's hope the apk debug works!

Comment: @Ismail hope it works out for you! Really heartbreaking to loose work.